# Plotting error bars from 2 axis

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm looking to plot the standard deviation of some array data I've been looking at in python however the data is averaged over both longitude and latitude (Axis 2,3 of my arrays). 
What I have so far is a monthly plot that looks like this but I can't get the standard deviations to work [Monthly plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC29C.png)

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to get around this problem. Here's the code I've used thus far.
Any help is much appreciated!

```
# import things
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import netCDF4

# [ date, hour, 0, lon, lat ]
temp = (f.variables['TEMP2'][:, 14:24, 0, :, :]) # temp at 2m
temp2 = (f.variables['TEMP2'][:, 0:14, 0, :, :])

# concatenate back to 24 hour period
tercon = np.concatenate((temp, temp2), axis=1)

ter1 = tercon.mean(axis=(2, 3))

rtemp = np.reshape(ter1, 672)-273

# X axis dates instead of times
date = np.arange(rtemp.shape[0])  # assume that delta time between data is 1
date21 = (date/24.)  # use days instead of hours

# change plot size for monthly
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 5

plt.plot(date21, rtemp , linestyle='-', linewidth=3.0, c='orange')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `errorbar` instead of `plot` and pass the precalculated standard deviations. The following adapted example uses random data to emulate your temperature data with an hourly resolution and accumulates the data and the standard deviation.

```
# import things
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# x-axis: day-of-month
date21 = np.arange(1, 31)
# generate random "hourly" data
hourly_temp = np.random.random(30*24)*10 + 20
# mean "temperature"
dayly_mean_temp = hourly_temp.reshape(24,30).mean(axis=0)
# standard deviation per day
dayly_std_temp = hourly_temp.reshape(24,30).std(axis=0)

# create a figure
figure = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
#add an axes to the figure
ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid()

ax.errorbar(date21, dayly_mean_temp , yerr=dayly_std_temp, fmt="--o", capsize=15, capthick=3, linestyle='-', linewidth=3.0, c='orange')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this it worked! I just had to figure out how to reshape my array properly :)